# Cannot Setup Instance of Greenplum Command Center Web Application on Greenplum Open Source Database with Centos 7 Cluster

Tags: command, center, greenplum

I have Greenplum Open Source Database running on a 3-node Centos 7 cluster.  The database is running and I am able to connect and run queries. Installation of Greenplum Command Center 2.0 works. When I try to configure an instance for the web appliance part using

```
gpcmdr --setup
```

I get the following error:

```
Creating instance schema in GPDB.  Please wait ...
Failed to setup Command Center instance [myCustomInstance]: 
Exception encountered while fetching GPDB version info Connection error for query select version();: 
FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "gpmon"
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf file for testing purposes.  This still generates the above error even with the **host all all ::1/128 trust**

```
# IPv6 local connections:
local    all         gpadmin         ident
host     all         gpadmin         127.0.0.1/28    trust
host     all         gpadmin         172.17.0.1/32       trust
host     all         gpadmin         192.168.65.90/32       trust
host     all         gpadmin         192.168.122.1/32       trust
host     all         gpadmin         ::1/128       trust
host     all         gpadmin         fe80::210:18ff:fe94:3768/128       trust
host     all         gpadmin         fe80::42:11ff:fea9:f1df/128       trust
host     all         gpadmin         fe80::b84c:8bff:fe4a:5ce2/128       trust
host     all         gpadmin         fe80::419:d7ff:fe90:6c48/128       trust
host     all         gpadmin         fe80::c0ff:81ff:feae:c1ec/128       trust
local    replication gpadmin         ident
host     replication gpadmin         samenet       trust
local    gpperfmon         gpmon         md5
host     all         gpmon         0.0.0.0/0    md5
host all gpmon ::1/128 md5    
host all all ::1/128 trust
```

Added in **host all gpmon ::1/128 md5** before last line.  Restarted the database and reran gpcmdr --setup.  Below are the log files

### gpperfmon/logs

```
2016-03-14 20:37:19|:-LOG: sounds like you have just upgraded your database, creating newer tables
2016-03-14 20:37:19|:-WARNING: [gpmondb.c:55] failed to execut query 'BEGIN;  CREATE TABLE public.log_alert_history (LIKE gp_toolkit.__gp_log_master_ext) DISTRIBUTED BY (logtime) PARTITION BY range (logtime)(START (date '2010-01-01') END (date '2010-02-01') EVERY (interval '1 month')); COMMIT;': ERROR:  relation "gp_toolkit.__gp_log_master_ext" does not exist
2016-03-14 20:37:19|:-WARNING: [gpmondb.c:1695] gpdb error ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
query: SELECT encoding FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d WHERE d.datname = 'gpperfmon'
2016-03-14 20:37:19|:-WARNING: [gpmondb.c:1769] gpdb failed to get server encoding.
```

## pg_logs/gpdb-2016-03-14_203718.csv

```
2016-03-14 20:39:15.586557 EDT,"gpmon","gpperfmon",p11521,th-217848000,"[local]",,2016-03-14 20:39:15 EDT,89956,con25,cmd1,seg-1,,dx64,x89956,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: SELECT sess_id, current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;",,,,,,"SELECT sess_id, current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;",0,,"postgres.c",1553,
2016-03-14 20:39:19.595436 EDT,"gpmon","gpperfmon",p11574,th-217848000,"[local]",,2016-03-14 20:39:19 EDT,89958,con26,cmd1,seg-1,,dx65,x89958,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: insert into system_history select * from _system_tail;",,,,,,"insert into system_history select * from _system_tail;",0,,"postgres.c",1553,
2016-03-14 20:39:19.628287 EDT,"gpmon","gpperfmon",p11580,th-217848000,"[local]",,2016-03-14 20:39:19 EDT,89958,con26,cmd2,seg-1,slice1,dx65,x89958,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: insert into system_history select * from _system_tail;",,,,,,"insert into system_history select * from _system_tail;",0,,"postgres.c",1096,
2016-03-14 20:39:19.681179 EDT,"gpmon","gpperfmon",p11588,th-217848000,"[local]",,2016-03-14 20:39:19 EDT,89961,con28,cmd1,seg-1,,dx66,x89961,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: insert into queries_history select * from _queries_tail;",,,,,,"insert into queries_history select * from _queries_tail;",0,,"postgres.c",1553,
2016-03-14 20:39:19.713717 EDT,"gpmon","gpperfmon",p11594,th-217848000,"[local]",,2016-03-14 20:39:19 EDT,89961,con28,cmd2,seg-1,slice1,dx66,x89961,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: insert into queries_history select * from _queries_tail;",,,,,,"insert into queries_history select * from _queries_tail;",0,,"postgres.c",1096,
```

Comment: Try to add `host     all         gpmon         ::1/128    md5` before the last line

Comment: Also check the error message in the GPDB database log and update the question adding it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `gp_toolkit.__gp_log_master_ext` doesn't exists. This table is created when gpdb generate its schema. Would you please try 
`"\d gp_toolkit.__gp_log_master_ext"` in gpdb and see if the table is normalized?